# Warning: strlen() expects parameter 1

Tags: php, magento

I am constantly seeing the following error in my `system.log` in magento. I have gone into the exact file but can not see anything wrong with it.

Has any one else experienced this?

> Warning: strlen() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given  in
>   /home/beerhawk/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Attribute.php
>   on line 93

Comment: And your code is in your IDE, I guess.

Comment: `strlen($val)`. Here `$val` must be a string and in your case it is an array

Comment: can you share a link of yours where you are facing this issue?

Comment: Did you _read_ the error message?

Comment: @Will Wright:- have you found any solution for this..bocz currently i am also facing this problem

Comment: @VishalSharma I haven't found a solution yet please let me know if you do

Comment: @WillWright: Actually i removed the strlen in Attribute.php file and add !empty() in the if condition.due to that error passed away .....

Answer (score 0):

The error message says everything - you passing an array to `strlen`, but strlen expects an string. If you want the length of and array, you should use `count`.

If you really want the length of an string, you should check your code, which have definitally some logical issues

Comment: Thanks for you answer, thats magento core code thats not been edited does that mean its maybe another module causing the issue?

Comment: Take a look at the stack trace of this error - there you should find the issuer module name