# Strlen() expects parameter to be string, array given in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, symfony-2.8, php-7.2

> **Warning:** strlen() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in symfony 4

[This is my error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMK8L.png)

How to solve this? Please Help.

Comment: Have you tried actually passing a string, not an array?

Comment: Welcome to SE! Could you please provide some sample code so we can identify and isolate the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function strlen() is used to retrieve the length of a string. So you should pass a string as a parameter not an array. The error is pretty much self explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

Summary and useful :

- **count()** : size of the an array
- **strlen()** : length of string

Several useful and relevant links:

[Warning: strlen() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in file... in line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50143398/warning-strlen-expects-parameter-1-to-be-string-array-given-in-file-in-li?rq=1)

[Warning: strlen() expects parameter 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23908794/warning-strlen-expects-parameter-1)

[Warning: strlen() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7259179/warning-strlen-expects-parameter-1-to-be-string-array-given)

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php

Calculate the length of the string of elements of a one-dimensional array:

```
<?php
$array=array("Hello","How are you","Are you good?","Yeah");
//This is not correct! : strlen($array);
foreach($array as $item)
{
$length=strlen($item);
echo $item." ( $length )\n";
}
?>
```

Output :

```
Hello ( 5 )
How are you ( 11 )
Are you good? ( 13 )
Yeah ( 4 )
```

---

The `strlen($array)` will occur a warning.

```
PHP Warning:  strlen() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in ... on line ...
```